# SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares

Tags: numpy, math, scipy, least-squares, svd

I have a problem with polyfit function. My data is:

```
value_to_cycle_slip_x_1 = [0.0, 30.0, 60.0, 90.0, 120.0, 150.0, 180.0, 210.0, 240.0, 270.0]
value_to_cycle_slip_y_1 = [1.4108499772846699, 1.410405956208706, 1.4104186482727528, 1.4109007231891155, 1.4058293923735619, 1.4069204106926918, 1.4082905240356922, 1.4050713926553726, 1.405217282474041, 1.4059784598648548]
```

And my function is:

```
a_coef_cycle_slip, b_coef_cycle_slip, c_coef_cycle_slip = polyfit(value_to_cycle_slip_x_1,value_to_cycle_slip_y_1,2).
```

When I use it in Python Console everything is ok, but when I use it in my script (executable) I receive an error:

```sh
"numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares".
```

Also, I try to use it on three different computers. With two (laptop) works normally, but, when I try to use it in stationary PC it does not work.
Maybe someone has already encountered such a problem and knows how to solve it?

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example?

Comment: This example work when I use it from a "finger" in Python Console. But does not work when calculate automate in my script.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same issue. I've found that after excluding rows of zeroes, the error message disappears.

```
df = df[df.column > 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. At now I reinstall my libraries with old versions and it works. But it's time to update the libraries and try to use it.